# Record/ save value of line generated

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have been engaged in a comprehensive study for several months and am now ready to transform it into a strategy. My code, which encompasses over 200 lines, is fully functional. In order to simplify my inquiry, I will do my utmost to present it succinctly. My study plots lines for take profit and stop loss, in accordance with predefined conditions. The line.new function was utilized to generate these lines.

As I progress towards converting my study into a strategy, I am encountering a challenge in communicating to pine script that the value of the plotted line represents my take profit or stop loss. To resolve this issue, I would like to create a variable named "takeProfit" that references the value of the line created using the line.new function. How can I accomplish this?

for example, this is my line function.

```
Line := line.new(bar_index, highPrice, bar_index+1, highPrice, width=2, color=color.red, extend=extend.both, style=line.style_dashed)
```

how do I create a variable called take profit and have it reference the value of the line created. so I can set a limit to the variable rather than the line. I am working with pinescript version 4. any help would be appreciated.

I cant just do something like that

```
strategy.entry("Long Position", strategy.long)
strategy.exit("Exit Long( TAKE PROFIT)", from_entry="Long Position", limit=highPrice)
```

as this will reference the current high price and not the high price when the line was generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `y` coordinate of the line using `line.get_y1()` or `line.get_y2()` function.

Keep in mind that while you visually see the line (since you have extended the line visually) the line doesn't exist on all bars, but only on the bars you've stated creating the line (`x1` to `x2`). If you want to get the `y` value of all the line you can use the `var` keyword. You can try something like this:

```
var line Line = na

if yourCondition
    Line := line.new(bar_index, highPrice, bar_index+1, highPrice, width=2, color=color.red, extend=extend.both, style=line.style_dashed)

tpLong = line.get_y1(Line)

strategy.entry("Long Position", strategy.long)
strategy.exit("Exit Long(TAKE PROFIT)", from_entry="Long Position", limit=tpLong)
```